# ARM NEON: Regular C code is faster than ARM Neon code in simple multiplication?

Tags: arm, simd, intrinsics, neon

I am implementing a simple multiplication for an array using ARM NEON intrinsics. The input is an uint8 array and the output is an uint16 array. However, the regular native code is faster than the NEON optimzied one. Can anyone help figure out how I can improve the NEON code?

My regular code is

```
    uint16_t scale_factor = 300;
    for(int i = 0; i < output_size; i++)
    {        
        out_16bit[i] = (uint16_t)(in_ptr[i] * scale_factor) ;
    }
```

My NEON code is

```
    uint16_t* out_ptr = out_16bit;
    uint8_t* in_ptr = in_8bit;
    uint16_t scale_factor = 300;

    for(int i = 0; i < out_size/16; i++)
    {
        uint8x16_t in_v0 = vld1q_u8(in_ptr);
        in_ptr += 16;

        uint16x8_t in_16_v0 = vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(in_v0));
        uint16x8_t in_16_v1 = vmovl_u8(vget_high_u8(in_v0));

        uint16x8_t res_0 = vmulq_n_u16(in_16_v0, scale_factor);
        uint16x8_t res_1 = vmulq_n_u16(in_16_v1, scale_factor);

        // code below takes long time
        vst1q_u16(out_ptr,res_0);  
        vst1q_u16(out_ptr+8,res_1);  
        out_ptr += 16;

    }
```

I also did some profiling and found out that if I comment out either `vst1q_u16`s or `out_ptr += 16`, the speed is fast. But if I keep both as above, it's very slow. So I guess it might be because the increment of pointer is waiting the finishing of `vst1q_u16`? Then I updated the NEON code to add some code between `vst1q_u16` and `out_ptr+=16` as below,

```
    uint8x16_t in_v0 = vld1q_u8(in_ptr);
    uint16x8_t in_16_v0 = vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(in_v0));
    uint16x8_t in_16_v1 = vmovl_u8(vget_high_u8(in_v0));

    uint16x8_t res_0 = vmulq_n_u16(in_16_v0, scale_factor);
    uint16x8_t res_1 = vmulq_n_u16(in_16_v1, scale_factor);
    vst1q_u16(out_ptr,res_0);  
    vst1q_u16(out_ptr+8,res_1);  
    for(int i = 1; i < out_size/16; i++)
    {

        in_v0 = vld1q_u8(in_ptr);
        in_16_v0 = vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(in_v0));
        in_16_v1 = vmovl_u8(vget_high_u8(in_v0));
    
        out_ptr += 16;

        res_0 = vmulq_n_u16(in_16_v0, scale_factor);
        res_1 = vmulq_n_u16(in_16_v1, scale_factor);

        vst1q_u16(out_ptr,res_0);  
        vst1q_u16(out_ptr+8,res_1);  

    
    }
```

But this change didn't work...Please help advise what I should do...Thank you.

Comment: Did you check whether your compiler autovectorizes your "regular code"? gcc [does](https://godbolt.org/z/s847cYsvq).

Comment: What optimisation switches did you use with your compiler ?

Comment: @EOF Thanks for the reply. May I ask how I can check whether the compiler did aotuvectorization? I am using clang 6 on ARMv8...

Comment: The denizens here may wish to know the exact compiler command line and might then want to take the code and compiler options over to godbolt to see what the compiler is telling the machine to do. You could consider that path.

Comment: "May I ask how I can check whether the compiler did autovectorization?" Basically, you read the assembly and see if it contains SIMD instructions.

Comment: The "very fast" cases might be misleading.  If you remove the stores, the compiler is likely to figure out that the loop doesn't actually do anything, and delete the whole thing.  Likewise if you don't increment `out_ptr`, the compiler may notice that only the last iteration matters, and skip all the others.  With an optimizing compiler, you can't really charge time to individual lines of code, certainly not by deleting them one by one.

Comment: Which toolchain? What compiler options? `aarch32`  or `aarch64`? And besides, you should never use immediate values such as 300 inside the function for benchmark purpose. Compilers cheat everywhere possible, and fixed values are a feast for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer, as in the comments, is auto-vectorization.
I'm unsure for clang 6, but certainly more recent clang will by default auto-vectorize to Neon when targeting Neon platforms, and it will be very hard to beat that auto-vectorization on something as simple as this multiplication.  Maybe with the best loop unrolling for your particular processor.  But it is very easy to be worse than auto-vectorization.  Godbolt is a very good way to go to compare, along with profiling all your changes.

All the comments make good points too.

For more documentation on best practice for Neon intrinsics, Arm's [Neon microsite](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon) has very useful information, especially the doc on [Optimizing C with Neon intrinsics](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102467/0100).